# Localized Date/Time with More Control

Tags: java, android, localization, threetenbp

I am using the ThreeTen-Backport (specifically [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP)) to display a timestamp in my project. I would like the displayed timestamp to be displayed in a localized format (based on the `Locale` of the system); which is easy enough using either of the [`DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDateTime-java.time.format.FormatStyle-) methods:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
        .ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.LONG)
        .withLocale(Locale.getDefault())
        .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());

String timestamp = formatter.format(Instant.now());
```

The issue is that I do not have much control over the output of the formatter with only four `FormatStyle` types (`SHORT`, `MEDIUM`, `LONG`, `FULL`). I am curious if there is a way to have much more fine-tuned control over the output, without losing the localization formatting.

---

Using the previous code, the resulting `timestamp` for the `"en_US"` locale would be:

```
"January 23, 2017 1:28:37 PM EST"
```

While the result for the `"ja_JP"` locale would be:

```
"2017年1月23日 13:28:37 GMT-5:00"
```

As you can see, each of the locales utilize a specific pattern, and use a default of either the 12 or 24 hour format. I would like to maintain the localized pattern, but change things like whether or not the time zone is displayed, or if the 12 or 24 hour format is used.

For example; if I could set both locales to use the 12 hour format, and remove the time zone; the results would look like this:

```
"January 23, 2017 1:28:37 PM"

"2017年1月23日 1:28:37午後"
```

Comment: ThreetenBP (and java.time-package in Java-8, too) has no such ability. My own time library for Android (Time4A) has partial support (at least supports the switch from 12 to 24 hour or back depending on Android user settings for the default locale).

Comment: I updated my answer and feel it is now closer to what Bryan is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the format string of the [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) with [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#getLocalizedDateTimePattern-java.time.format.FormatStyle-java.time.format.FormatStyle-java.time.chrono.Chronology-java.util.Locale-).  Once you have that string then you can manipulate it with the [`DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-) method.

```
    String fr = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(FormatStyle.LONG, FormatStyle.FULL, IsoChronology.INSTANCE, Locale.FRANCE);
    //d MMMM yyyy HH' h 'mm z
    String ge = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(FormatStyle.LONG, FormatStyle.FULL, IsoChronology.INSTANCE, Locale.GERMAN);
    //d. MMMM yyyy HH:mm' Uhr 'z
    String ca = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(FormatStyle.LONG, FormatStyle.FULL, IsoChronology.INSTANCE, Locale.CANADA);
    //MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss 'o''clock' a z
    String en = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(FormatStyle.LONG, FormatStyle.FULL, IsoChronology.INSTANCE, Locale.ENGLISH);
    //MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a z
```

In [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) you can specify individual units of the date with symbolic characters and the method ofPattern.  The number of symbolic characters that you use per unit can also affect what gets displayed:

- `M` will get you the month in digits.
- `MM` will get you months as two digits, even if the month is less than 10.
- `MMM` should get you the month name.

See the section "Patterns for Formatting and Parsing" on
[`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) documentation.

The pattern below gives you a four digit year, two digit month, and two digit day.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now(); //For reference
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy MM dd");
String formattedString = localDate.format(formatter);
```

Comment: The OP still wants localizable patterns, meaning even localizable literals inside of patterns. Your post is therefore not an answer at all.

Comment: This Answer still seems incomplete. Perhaps you can follow through with the exact requests made in the Question: (a) specify if the format is 12 or 24 hour, (b) specify if the time zone or weekday is displayed. Also, I believe your last code example should specify the `Locale`.

Comment: @ProgrammersBlock thank you - your answer helped me to find how change 2-digit year to 4-digit year and still have support for locale:
String localizedPattern = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(dateStyle, timeStyle, IsoChronology.INSTANCE, locale);
String localizedPatternWithFullYear = localizedPattern.replace("yy", "yyyy");
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(localizedPatternWithFullYear).withLocale(locale).withZone(zoneId)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `FormatStyle`'s (AFAIK) is that they use predefined patterns. Although, it's possible to get them and manipulate/change the pattern to fit your needs.

I'm not using Android specific environment, so I'm not sure how well this code will work for you. I'm using **Java JDK 1.7.0_79** and **ThreeTen Backport 1.3.4**. I'm also using **America/New_York** timezone for my tests - I guess it corresponds to **EST**.

I noticed some differences from your environment:

- using `FormatStyle.LONG` for japanese locale gives me `2017/01/23 13:28:37 EST`
- I had to use `FormatStyle.FULL` to get `2017年1月23日 13時28分37秒 EST`

But I think this doesn't invalidate my tests.

First I used `java.text.DateFormat` class to get the localized pattern as a `String`. Then I did some replacements to this `String`, according to the configuration wanted:

- look for `HH`, `hh`, `H` or `h` and change to use 12 or 24 hour format (I replaced keeping the same number of letters)
- remove or add `z` (or `Z`): to remove or add a timezone
- avoid literals: some patterns (like in **pt_BR** locale) have a literal `h` after the hours (like `HH'h'` which becomes `13h`), so I had to take care of this when replacing

The code to create the formatter is:

```
// creates a formatter with the specified style, locale and zone
// there are options to use 12 or 24 hour format and include or not a timezone
public DateTimeFormatter getFormatter(FormatStyle style, Locale locale, ZoneId zone,
                                      boolean use24HourFormat, boolean useTimezone) {
    // get the format correspondent to the style and locale
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(style.ordinal(), style.ordinal(), locale);

    // *** JDK 1.7.0_79 returns SimpleDateFormat ***
    // If Android returns another type, check if it's possible to get the pattern from this type
    if (dateFormat instanceof SimpleDateFormat) {
        // get the pattern String for the locale
        String pattern = ((SimpleDateFormat) dateFormat).toPattern();

        if (use24HourFormat) {
            if (pattern.contains("hh")) { // check the "hh" hour format
                // hh not surrounded by ' (to avoid literals)
                pattern = pattern.replaceAll("((?<!\')hh)|(hh(?!\'))", "HH");
            } else { // check the "h" hour format
                // h not surrounded by ' (to avoid literals)
                pattern = pattern.replaceAll("((?<!\')h)|(h(?!\'))", "H");
            }
        } else {
            if (pattern.contains("HH")) { // check the "HH" hour format
                // HH not surrounded by ' (to avoid literals)
                pattern = pattern.replaceAll("((?<!\')HH)|(HH(?!\'))", "hh");
            } else { // check the "H" hour format
                // H not surrounded by ' (to avoid literals)
                pattern = pattern.replaceAll("((?<!\')H)|(H(?!\'))", "h");
            }
        }

        if (useTimezone) {
            // checking if already contains a timezone (the naive way)
            if (!pattern.contains("z") && !pattern.contains("Z")) {
                // I'm adding z in the end, but choose whatever pattern you want for the timezone (it can be Z, zzz, and so on)
                pattern += " z";
            }
        } else {
            // 1 or more (z or Z) not surrounded by ' (to avoid literals)
            pattern = pattern.replaceAll("((?<!\')[zZ]+)|([zZ]+(?!\'))", "");
        }

        // create the formatter for the locale and zone, with the customized pattern
        return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern, locale).withZone(zone);
    }

    // can't get pattern string, return the default formatter for the specified style/locale/zone
    return DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(style).withLocale(locale).withZone(zone);
}
```

Some usage examples (my default `Locale` is **pt_BR** - Brazilian Portuguese):

```
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
Instant instant = ZonedDateTime.of(2017, 1, 23, 13, 28, 37, 0, zone).toInstant();
FormatStyle style = FormatStyle.FULL;

// US locale, 24-hour format, with timezone
DateTimeFormatter formatter = getFormatter(style, Locale.US, zone, true, true);
System.out.println(formatter.format(instant)); // Monday, January 23, 2017 13:28:37 PM EST
// US locale, 24-hour format, without timezone
formatter = getFormatter(style, Locale.US, zone, true, false);
System.out.println(formatter.format(instant)); // Monday, January 23, 2017 13:28:37 PM 
// US locale, 12-hour format, with timezone
formatter = getFormatter(style, Locale.US, zone, false, true);
System.out.println(formatter.format(instant)); // Monday, January 23, 2017 1:28:37 PM EST
// US locale, 12-hour format, without timezone
formatter = getFormatter(style, Locale.US, zone, false, false);
System.out.println(formatter.format(instant)); // Monday, January 23, 2017 1:28:37 PM 

// japanese locale, 24-hour format, with timezone
formatter = getFormatter(style, Locale.JAPAN, zone, true, true);
System.out.println(formatter.format(instant)); // 2017年1月23日 13時28分37秒 EST
// japanese locale, 24-hour format, without timezone
formatter = getFormatter(style, Locale.JAPAN, zone, true, false);
System.out.println(formatter.format(instant)); // 2017年1月23日 13時28分37秒 
// japanese locale, 12-hour format, with timezone
formatter = getFormatter(style, Locale.JAPAN, zone, false, true);
System.out.println(formatter.format(instant)); // 2017年1月23日 1時28分37秒 EST
// japanese locale, 12-hour format, without timezone
formatter = getFormatter(style, Locale.JAPAN, zone, false, false);
System.out.println(formatter.format(instant)); // 2017年1月23日 1時28分37秒 

// pt_BR locale, 24-hour format, with timezone
formatter = getFormatter(style, Locale.getDefault(), zone, true, true);
System.out.println(formatter.format(instant)); // Segunda-feira, 23 de Janeiro de 2017 13h28min37s EST
// pt_BR locale, 24-hour format, without timezone
formatter = getFormatter(style, Locale.getDefault(), zone, true, false);
System.out.println(formatter.format(instant)); // Segunda-feira, 23 de Janeiro de 2017 13h28min37s 
// pt_BR locale, 12-hour format, with timezone
formatter = getFormatter(style, Locale.getDefault(), zone, false, true);
System.out.println(formatter.format(instant)); // Segunda-feira, 23 de Janeiro de 2017 01h28min37s EST
// pt_BR locale, 12-hour format, without timezone
formatter = getFormatter(style, Locale.getDefault(), zone, false, false);
System.out.println(formatter.format(instant)); // Segunda-feira, 23 de Janeiro de 2017 01h28min37s
```

---

**Notes:**

- The method `DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance` returns a `SimpleDateFormat`, but I'm not sure if it works the same way in Android. You can check if it returns a different type and if it's possible to get the pattern `String` from this class (if it's not, then I don't know another way of doing it).
- I created options to change the hour format (12 or 24) and include or remove a timezone. But you can create as many options as you need - once you have the pattern `String`, you can do anything with it
- My regular expressions are (IMO) a little bit ugly. But I'm not a regex expert and I'm not sure how they can be improved. I've tested them with some locales and they seem to be fine, but there might be some particular case where they fail (although I haven't tested enough to find it)
- If you want to add the offset (like `-05:00`) you can use the `xxx` pattern (instead of `z`). If you want the offset with **GMT** (like `GMT-05:00`) you can use the `ZZZZ` pattern.
- I'm not sure if all patterns have the `z` as the timezone (they can use `Z` or `x`), so you might change the code to look for the other patterns. In my tests I didn't find anything different from `z`, but anyway I'd recommend a double check on this just to make sure.
- I'm checking if the pattern already has a timezone by doing `pattern.contains("z")` - a very naive/silly way because it doesn't handle a `z` literal (inside quotes). Maybe this could be changed to use a regex as well (although I didn't find a locale with a pattern that has a `z` literal).

Comment: This is a good work around. The only issue I see with the current code is the lack of the AM/PM symbol for the 12-hour format; which would be easy enough to implement, but if I come across another circumstance that I need finer control over I would need to add conditionals for each case. This just seems like a lot of extra work for something that should've been built into the framework.

Comment: To add AM/PM, you must add the pattern `a`, but you'll need to find the correct position - after the whole block of hour/minute/second pattern - which is not straightforward as the patterns vary a lot (or you could assume it's always in the end, but before timezone). As the `FormatStytle`'s patterns seem to be pre-defined and built-in in the JVM, I don't see another way of doing it.